# Full page screenshot including url in Cypress

Tags: cypress

> How to take full page Screenshot including URL in Cypress? I have tried below code but it does not include the url.
> Cypress.Screenshot.defaults({
> capture:'fullPage',
> })

Comment: Try `runner` instead of `fullPage`.

Answer (score 0):

It will capture the full-screen screenshots.

```
cy.screenshot({capture:'runner'})
```